# Change css according to number of classes

Tags: html, css

When you have more than 2 times the "doc" class in the "section" class, I need all the "dum" classes to agree as I indicate in css, but the first "dum" is not just the second.

```css
.section .doc .dum {
    color: red;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: .3;
}

.section .doc:nth-last-of-type(n + 2), 
.section .doc:nth-last-of-type(n + 2) ~ .doc .dum {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="doc">
    <div class="dum">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="doc">
    <div class="dum">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="section">
  <div class="doc">
    <div class="dum">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your expectation is that the second section also display without opacity. Is that correct?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai The first section, as it has more than 2 "dum" elements, must both have opacity 1, and the second section, as it only has 1 "dum" element, must have opacity .3

Comment: that is not possible using only CSS. You need to have Javascript or JQuery. Your expectation is based on child element count apply styles to parent elements. In CSS, we don't have option to travel from child to parent

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I saw an example in codepen that this works (without js), but when implementing for mine, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: can you plz share codepen? we can check it out.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/wgGpeP Remove a li in the "example-from" class, I've had js completely, and you'll see it works.

Comment: :) that is SCSS/SASS not pure CSS. You can add conditions in SCSS/SASS but not in pure CSS

Comment: If I understand you well, you could use a selector like this: `.section .doc:nth-last-child(n + 2) .dum, .section .doc + .doc .dum {opacity: 1;}`

Comment: @AmauryHanser That's right :) Thank you. Can you put as an answer for me to mark as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Disclaimer, it gives a soution to your problem, but not to your question as you phrased it.***

You're willing to check if there is more than two consecutive elements with the class `.doc`, and if yes, have the rule `opacity: 1;` to their child `.dum`.

To rephrase it, you could say:

- if `.doc` is directly after `.doc`, which translate to `.doc + .doc` in CSS.
- if `.doc` is at least the second child, starting from the end, which translate to `.doc:nth-last-child(n + 2)`.

Combined, you get: `.doc + .doc .dum, .doc:nth-last-child(n + 2) .dum`

Now, you're sure that if there is only one `.doc`, it won't be selected because the condition `.donc:nth-last-child(n + 2)` will be false.

```css
.section .doc .dum {
    color: red;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: .3;
}

.section .doc:nth-last-child(n + 2) .dum, 
.section .doc + .doc .dum {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="doc">
    <div class="dum">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="doc">
    <div class="dum">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="section">
  <div class="doc">
    <div class="dum">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```